# Not able to connect localstack with spring clound

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-aws

I have setup locastack in my local pc. I am able to **create, send and receive** in the queue using command line.

How  am trying to connect **SpringBoot application with the localstcak queue**.

I am not finding any tutorial which will guide me how we **can read data from localstack queue using spring cloud**.

I have a class which looks like this

```
@Component
@Profile("aws")
public class EventListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VisitsQueue.class);

    @Value("${sqs.queuename}")
    private String queueName;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @RuntimeUse
    @SqsListener("${sqs.queuename}")
    public void receiveMessage(String message, @Header(value = "SenderId", required = false) String senderId,
            @Headers Map<String, Object> allHeaders) {
        LOGGER.info("Received message with content {}", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to get the test running in the meantime? If it still does not work, please raise a ticket at https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb